# Ionic 4 color attribute in custom components

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

We are doing **custom components in ionic 4**, we want it to have ionic attributes like the `color` attribute to affect its internal ionic components ... **Any hint about how can this be done ?** , without doing regular binding like `[color]=" 'blue-lagoon' "

Comment: Override the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

To do this is easy...

In this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@paulstelzer/ionic-4-how-to-add-more-colors-and-use-them-as-color-in-buttons-and-more-7175ab4ae4e7) are all the information.

But in summary you need to do this steps:

**1.**

Go to this [page](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/theming/color-generator?source=post_page---------------------------), here you find a color generator of ionic, you can use the primary color section, put your hexadecimal color and below is generated the code to that color:

For example ill use #5e3f53 so the code generate it will be:

```
--ion-color-primary: #5e3f53;
--ion-color-primary-rgb: 94,63,83;
--ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-primary-shade: #533749;
--ion-color-primary-tint: #6e5264;
```

**2.**

Now on go to file src/theme/variables.scss and paste inside :root{}

```
--ion-color-myCustom: #5e3f53;
--ion-color-myCustom-rgb: 94,63,83;
--ion-color-myCustom-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-myCustom-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-myCustom-shade: #533749;
--ion-color-myCustom-tint: #6e5264;
```

**3.**

and then go to the file src/global.scss and paste the following code:

```
.ion-color-myCustom {
  --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-myCustom) !important;
  --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-myCustom-rgb) !important;
  --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-myCustom-contrast) !important;
  --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-myCustom-contrast-rgb) !important;
  --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-myCustom-shade) !important;
  --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-myCustom-tint) !important;
}
```

**4**

Now you can use your custom color wherever you want, obviously with the name that you define it.

[image: code here]

And that's it.

[image: result - color changed]

Or if the color property is not allowed that I guess is your case for your post, create a class, id or style.

[image: code]

and can use your color with this way:

[image: code css]

I hope I've helped :)